# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}{}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \ ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2n}}\right)$

Tags: limits

> $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}{}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 3}} + \ ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2n}}\right)$$

It doesn't simplify out

Comment: Hint: how many terms are there?  What would the next term be if there was one more term included?

Comment: You have $2n+1$ terms and each one of them is pretty close to $\frac{1}{n}$, hence the limit is trivially $2$ by squeezing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

\begin{align}
&&\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}&&\leq&&
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}&&\leq&&
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2}}\\
\implies &&\frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}&&\leq&&
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}&&\leq&&
\frac{2n+1}{n}\\
\implies &&\frac{2+\frac1n}{\sqrt{1+\frac2n}}&&\leq&&
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}}&&\leq&&
2+\frac{1}{n}
\end{align}

For the last part of the LHS inequality, we simply multiplied numerator and denominator by $\frac1n$.
Letting $n\to\infty$, we conclude the limit sought equals $2$.

Comment: You can also set the lower limit to $$ \frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}} = \frac{2n+1}{n+1} $$

Comment: @Dylan Yes, that would be more elegant I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Let your limit be $I_n$

now 
$$\frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}<I_n<\frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{n^2}}$$

Edit: Fimpellizieri's answer better explains this